# Difference in running between different patches of java

Tags: java, version, patch

I have java version "1.6.0_23 installed on one of the production servers.
I am trying to create a replica of the production server on one of the VM servers.
on that vm server java version installed is java version "1.6.0".

I can see on production 23 patch is installed

Will there be any conflicts in the different pathces of java 1.6  running.?

Answer (score 0):

So far as I can tell, there is no difference that would cause an issue.  Most of the changes appear to be bug fixes and performance improvements.  I find it unlikely that within version 1.6 any API changes would have taken place so that shouldn't be an issue.  I only see some swing class changes regarding unintended behaviour, though that wouldn't cause your server any grief.  If you want to check for yourself the patch notes for this version of Java are available here:[1.6 Patch Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/releasenotes-136954.html)